# Label can only appear inside switch statement

Tags: swift, notifications

I am getting an error with my stock app and it is giving me a error. Here is my code.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

I am getting two errors.

1. Default' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement
2. Expected member name following '.'

Answer (score 0):

The above code compiles for me. The second error is due to there not being something directly after a ".". Your first error could make sense if you accidentally typed something like:

```
NotificationCenter. default.addObserver(...)
```

Because then the compiler is interpreting the default as the default case object that you use in a switch-statement, which is obviously not what you want.

Check that you have no spaces between your "."s